# How do I win the mock battle against the USS Republic?

Tags: star-trek-25th-anniversary

I just started *Star Trek: 25th Anniversary* and apparently I'm so bad that I can't even win the mock battle against the USS Republic. After reading the manual closely, I figured out the controls and can last about 30 seconds in a battle with the Republic before being defeated. My methodology so far is:

1. Arm shields
2. Arm weapons
3. Turn on target analysis (can't figure out what this actually does)
4. Figure out where the ship is using the ship position monitor
5. Turn to face it (using the mouse)
6. Unload phasers at long range and photon torpedoes at short range
7. If I survive my first encounter and can't see the ship anymore, tell Scotty to repair the shields (if those are fixed, then stuff below it won't get damaged, right?)
8. Repeat steps 5-7

Invariably what happens is that I'm chasing the Republic, then it turns to face me and unloads its weapons. I continue to unload my weapons (like the "Fire Everything!" scene in *Wrath of Khan*), but it seems they always destroy the *Enterprise* (or at least, that's what the simulation says).

I figure that if I can't beat the USS Republic in a mock battle, there's no way that I can beat the real enemies in the game. How do I beat it? Or is this supposed to be a *Kobayashi Maru* no-win scenario?

Comment: FTR, I am really not sure how this game is playable without the manual and star chart. It might be possible but I'm sure it would be extremely painful. There's also an awesome clue book that isn't just a list of hints, it's the missions themselves written out as an episodic story, and gameplay hints are hidden in the dialog and narration. If you bought this on GOG.com, they should be available for download, but I've also been able to find them by googling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to beat the USS Republic in the initial battle, as shown in the following video at about 5:50...

There's no real secret to winning the battle that I can find, all of your tactics are correct, but there are a few others that can help in space combat (some of which you already noted, but I'll include them for posterity):

*Screenshots are from the GOG.com version of the game, and from the digital official game materials included with that purchase*

#### Prepare for Battle

Immediately hit <kbd>S</kbd> to raise your shields and <kbd>W</kbd> to arm weapons

#### Tracking

Use the radar to figure out where your opponent is. The shot below shows the Republic (green dot) at my six o'clock:

[image: radar]

#### Target Analysis

Spock can give you damage analysis on enemy ships, but it hides your own ship diagnostic information while it's active:

[image: target1]
[image: target2]

#### Vary Your Speed

Speed up or slow down using the numeric keys as described below, in the official game manual:

[image: speed manual]

#### Repairing

If you take damage, use the <kbd>D</kbd> key to pull up the "Repair" menu and tell Scotty to get to work:

[image: repair menu]

Left to right, these are your shields, phasers, torpedos, sensors, bridge, hull, and engines (I guess warp and impulse are lumped together).

#### Integrity Monitoring

Monitor your shield and hull integrity using the diagrams on the left and right of the bridge. These can tell you which way to orient your ship so you can keep damaged areas away from enemy fire.

[image: L diagram]
[image: R diagram]

Comment: I guess there were two things I wasn't really doing: varying my speed and monitoring which areas had integrity. I appreciate the detailed explanations!